# Add or Copy Crystal Report dll references from GAC to Bin Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, bin

I am using Visual Studio 2008, with crystal report 10.5.3700.0.
We want to copy crystal report dll from GAC to BIN Folder. 
I used following solution -
 right-click on my project - Go to Property Pages -go to references - Removed GAC References And added crystal report dll (which is in "C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\managed" this folder) with "Browse" option.
But That References not added in BIN Folder. What is the Solution?

Comment: What effort have you put so far?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on dll then set CopyLocal=true;

Or

In project property/publish/application files/ -> set publish status to include.